# Нет перевода фразы "Report this ad" в рекламном блоке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, реклама

Не переведена фраза:

> Report this ad

[image: Рекламный блок]

Comment: Там заодно весь интерфейс не переведен ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14393

Добавил перевод:

> Пожаловаться на эту рекламу

Comment: Ещё надо кнопку "пожаловаться на этот перевод" рядом с каждым предложением.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ (¬‿¬ )

Comment: О, применилось.

Comment: Там ещё текстов нашли)

Comment: @Qwertiy видел. Добавлю вечером.